# Lotus Notes 8.5.2 won't start

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, notes

Lotus Notes 8.5.2 installed ok but won't start.
Tried installing FP1 but that won't install. Re-installed Notes 8.5.2 but still won't start.
Symphony 3.0 starts and runs fine.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,
G.

Comment: Can you run it from the command line and paste any errors or warnings to your question?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on a VMWare image of ubuntu 10.10.  I have documented my process at http://metkhoo.blogspot.com/2010/10/lotus-notes-853-on-ubuntu-meerkat-1010.html
Hope that helps